# Export data in Processing Android mode

Tags: java, android, export, processing

I'm able to export data in Processing but not in Processing's Android mode. My code looks like this:

```
PrintWriter output;    

void setup()
{    
output = createWriter("Data.txt");    
...
}

...

output.println("test");    
output.flush();    
output.close();
```

It doesn't return an error message but simply won't create the file. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: How are you testing whether the file is created? A google search of "processing android createwriter" returns a ton of results.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. When I add a directory to createWriter (e.g. createWriter("/data/Data.txt") it doesn't show up in the data folder, that's how I test if the file is created. A google search didn't help me either. This: http://forum.processing.org/one/topic/where-do-the-files-i-create-with-createwriter-end-up.html seems to be similar to my problem, but I have no SD card, so it didn't work for me